# Horizontal table HTML in PartialView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, partial-views

I'm working on Web application project using Asp.Net Core MVC where i have a view that displays a Horizontal table. I'm using partial view to achieve that but i'm stuck on how i can represent fixed five rows as following:

1. Day
2. Date
3. Appropriate
4. InAppropriate
5. NoInteraction

each row will print the values dynamically.

Here is My View where it pass everything as expected.

```
<form method="get" asp-action="details">
    <table class="table order-list">
        <thead>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SessionList.Count; i++)
            {
        <partial name="_ChartDetailsPartial" for="@Model.SessionList[i]"

                 />}

        </thead>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Here is my partialView where i want to display and arrange everything there.

```
@model TestApplication.Models.ViewModels.SessionViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_ChartDetailsPartial";
}

<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />

<tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Day)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="200">Date</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Date)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline limegreen">Appropriate Data</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Appropriate)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline red">InAppropriate Data</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NotAppropriate)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline darkgray">No Interaction Data</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NoInteraction)</td>
    }
</tr>
```

What i'm trying to achieve is similar to the figure below:

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps add the desired result as an image or text representation? I'm having difficulty visualizing what you want to do? But for starters the table html is wrong anyway. Should be `<tr><th> </th><tr><td> </td></tr>` not `<tr><th> </th><td>...`

Comment: You can check the figure above.

Comment: On a side note I'd move the whole table to the partial view and `<input>` is an invalid child of `<table>` , `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tr>`; it belongs in a `<td>` or `<th>`

Comment: Could you share what is your model like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<SessionViewModel> SessionList { get; set; }
}
public class SessionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Date { get; set; }
    public int Appropriate { get; set; }
    public int NotAppropriate { get; set; }
    public int NoInteraction { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model TestViewModel
<form method="get" asp-action="details">
    <table class="table order-list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.SessionList.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <th>@i</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <partial name="_ChartDetailsPartial" for="@Model.SessionList" />
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Partial View:

```
@model List<SessionViewModel>
<tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id" />
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Day)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width="200">Date</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Date)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline limegreen">Appropriate Data</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Appropriate)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline red">InAppropriate Data</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].NotAppropriate)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline darkgray">No Interaction Data</th>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].NoInteraction)</td>
    }
</tr>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
<form method="get" asp-action="details">
    <table class="table order-list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                @for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
                {
                   <th>@i</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <partial name="_ChartDetailsPartial" for="@Model.SessionList"/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Partial view

```
@model List<TestApplication.Models.ViewModels.SessionViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_ChartDetailsPartial";
}

@for (int i = 0; i < Model; i++)
{
    var session = Model[i];

<tr>
    <td>Day</td>
    @for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
        <td>
              <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
              @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Day)
        </td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="200">Date</td>
    @for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Date)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-decoration: underline limegreen">Appropriate Data</td>
    @for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Appropriate)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-decoration: underline red">InAppropriate Data</td>
    @for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NotAppropriate)</td>
    }
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-decoration: underline darkgray">No Interaction Data</td>
    @for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NoInteraction)</td>
    }
</tr>
}
```

Comment: This code result in "Vertical" table.. which is not my case, i need it to be "Horizontally" as shown in the figure above.

Comment: Do you have multiple vertical tables? To understand why you use this code block`@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SessionList.Count; i++)`